# Unable to add margin-right to my code

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add `padding-right` to a [code](http://classicbackpack.com/). Inspite of trying I could not get it done (even tried `margin-right`).

```
.widget-title {
    color: #454545;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px !important; /*First tried it without !important but it did not worked in both the cases.*/
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Here is the markup,

```
<li id="categories-2" class="widget-container widget_categories"><h3 class="widget-title">Categories</h3>       <ul>
```

Please help me out how can I do it.

Comment: The style is applied, question is what you expect to see ? [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CxREU/)....

Comment: I'm going to take a huge wild guess and wonder whether you're actually asking how to get that RSS icon beside your "Classic Backpack – Google News" section on your right-hand sidebar to appear to the right of the text. If so, you need to add `float: right;` to the image. If that's not what you're asking, you need to explain what the problem is that you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Put your `<h3>` tags on `display:block;`. Once you have a block element (layer or div/span) you can add padding to it.

On a side note: there's no added value for SEO with `h3` tags inside a `ul` element. You should use `<span class="widget-title">my title</span>`. Then you don't need `display: block;`.

**EDIT:** Since I find this interesting, I went to look for prove to my previous statement about SEO added value:
http://www.seobythesea.com/2010/05/google-defines-semantic-closeness-as-a-ranking-signal/ (see: **HTML Formatting used to Determine Semantic Structures**) where they seem to claim the opposite. But just imagine someone looking for "Categories backpack" targeting the `h3` and a keyword inside the `ul`. People don't search like that imho.
It makes sense when people find your content with "high sierra Backpack". So the `h3` doesn't add value in search terms so to speak and is more of a visual indicator in your case.